# Keras Embeddings - how to match embedding vector with correct category?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've got Keras model using functional api trained on samples with Embedding layer, embedding Class of 10 unique values into 4 dim vector.
After I load embedded weights

```
embeddings_pclass = model.get_layer('Class').get_weights()
```

I get list of 10 vectors say [.3,-.1,.9,.1] and so on. This is all fine and as planned. But I can't find anywhere how to do sort of reverse engineering to find out which Class matches with which vector ? My classes unique values are 1,2,3,5,7,8,9,12,15,19. Should I expect this is asc order of unique values to vectors in the list ??

Thanks
E

Comment: Your model expecting index of embedding vector as input of Embedding layer (not class value). So you anyway transform class value to embedding index somewhere in the program.

Comment: I am confused. Could you please be more specific what your inputs and output are, and what you expect to come out? So you have 10 classes for an NLP task, but you only get four numbers out of an embedding layer? Also feel free to attach your network.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit function in `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` to obtain classes, but you can view it as a problem of finding the nearest embedding in the weights matrix. The weight matrix rows correspond to classes (as you correctly guessed) so you can use `argmin` to get class value.

```
def get_class (emb_layer, encoded):
    w = emb_layer.get_weights()[0]
    distances = tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(w - encoded, axis = 1)
    return tf.math.argmin(distances).numpy()

get_class(model.get_layer('Class'), tf.constant([.3,-.1,.9,.1]))
```